# Angular 2 Library Global Styles

Tags: css, angular, angular-cli

I am creating an Angular 2 Library. I want to add global styling to unify the font. I tried to put styles in styles.css, which didn't help. It seems like styles.css is not included as part of the library. When I do `ng serve` and make changes to styles.css, nothing happens and the compiler doesn't even refresh.

In `.angular-cli.json` file, I included styles.css.

[image]

Any idea? What is the best way to add global styles to Angular 2 Library?

Comment: If you want a stylesheet that is applicable to the whole application you could put it in the `<HEAD>` of your `index.html`.

Comment: can you add your complete `.angular-cli.json` file content, style are relative to your source path, may be there is issue with path.

Comment: @Raven, since this is an Angular Library, there is separated html file. There isn't a `index.html` to <link> `styles.css` or other information.

Comment: @MadhuRanjanI have edited my post. The root is `src` and I have `styles.css` in the src folder.